# Будет ли такой using занимать меньше ресурсов при запуске приложения?

Tags: c#, using

Будет ли подобное импортирование в C# занимать меньше памяти при запуске программы:

```
using DataReceivedEventArgs = System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs;
using ProcessStartInfo = System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
using Process = System.Diagnostics.Process;
```

или же нет смысла писать лишние строчки и такое импортирование эффективнее?:

```
using System.Diagnostics
```

Comment: Это не импорт в рантайме, как в питоне или пхп,  а указание компилятору где искать при компиляции. И потому на память не влияет. Да и вообще = имеет делать когда это сокращает использование. Например какой то очень длинный дженерик или когда не избежать конфликта имен. В вашем случае использование = лишено смысла

Comment: @vitidev Почему не в ответ?

Comment: @vitidev оставьте ответ, я его засчитаю, получите честно заработанные баллы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пространство имен в `c#` - способ структурировать классы, а также предотвратить конфликт имен, когда 2 класса называются одинаково. Директива `using namespace` определяет указание компилятору "где искать" класс, который и будет использоваться в рантайме. Используется в процессе компиляции и в рантайме уже не существует. А значит любые допустимые изменения синтаксиса влияют лишь на читабельность кода, но не на выполнение.